# DHT11 and PMS3003 Code. How to save in a specific path? Wrong formatting?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3, usb, rpi.gpio

I am using pms3003 sensor and dht11 sensor. I got g3 code from https://github.com/Thomas-Tsai/pms3003-g3 (thank you). This code displays to a text file, 20x4 lcd(separate driver), and terminal.

1. How do I save my data to a specific folder? My code below doesn't work. (save_path) It saves in the same folder where I run the code.
2. (Not important but..) And why does the code looping some seconds off?
   (15:57:50, 15:58:01, 15:58:03, 15:58:05, 15:58:08, 15:58:10  )
3. And is there something wrong with the code or bad formatting? It's working but can I make it simpler?

#### Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Adafruit_DHT
import time
import datetime
import os
import g3
import sys
import I2C_LCD_driver
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import serial
import os
from struct import *
from time import gmtime, strftime
debug=1

actual_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", gmtime())

mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()

save_path = '/home/pi/pms3003/data'
file = open("PMdata -" + str(actual_time) + ".txt","w")

air=g3.g3sensor()

while True:

    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11,4)

    pmdata=air.read("/dev/ttyUSB0")

    print ('Timestamp: {:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    print pmdata
    print "PM1: %s " % pmdata[3]
    print "PM10: %s " % pmdata[4]
    print "PM2.5: %s " % pmdata[5]

    print "Temperature: %s " % temperature
    print "Humidity: %s " % humidity    

    mylcd.lcd_display_string("T={0:0.1f}C H={1:0.1f}%%".format(temperature,humidity), 1)
    mylcd.lcd_display_string("PM1: %s" % pmdata[3], 2)
    mylcd.lcd_display_string("PM2.5: %s " % pmdata[5], 3)
    mylcd.lcd_display_string("PM10: %s "  % pmdata[4], 4)

    file.write('Timestamp: {:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    file.write("  Humidity: %s" % humidity)
    file.write("  Temperature in C: %s" % temperature)
    file.write("    PM 1: %s" % pmdata[3])
    file.write("    PM 2.5: %s" % pmdata[5])
    file.write("    PM 10: %s" % pmdata[4])
    file.write("\n")
    file.flush()

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Try Steve's approach to fixing the bug. As for code review, may I suggest you post the (corrected) code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? You might get bigger response there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, change:

```
save_path = '/home/pi/pms3003/data' 
file = open("PMdata -" + str(actual_time) + ".txt","w")
```

to :

```
save_path = '/home/pi/pms3003/data/' 
file = open(save_path + "PMdata -" + str(actual_time) + ".txt","w")
```

In your original code, you are assigning your desired file path to the save_path variable, but you are not using that variable when opening the file. You also need a **/** to separate the path and file name.

As for why it does not have an entry for every second. Think about the last line of your code:

```
time.sleep(1)
```

This will sleep for 1 second, but you have not considered the amount of time the rest of your code takes to execute. say it takes 0.1 seconds. Every loop, therefore, takes more than a second to complete 0.1 seconds to run the code and 1 second of sleep time. As a result for every 10 or eleven loops, the code will have taken 1 extra second to complete - essentially skipping a second in your output. Also, there is some variability in the sleep function itself. You can read more about the precision of the sleep function in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133857/how-accurate-is-pythons-time-sleep). You mention that this is not a major issue, I would add that most applications probably do not need to measure or log this info once a second.

In terms of improving your code here are a few observations:

- there are no code comments,
- you have duplicate imports (e.g. `import time` and  `from time import gmtime, strftime`, and you import os twice, on lines 6 and 12), and
- you don't have any error handling.

There are other things I might suggest, but those are the biggest issues.